# DOM walking function not working

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple function that performs a task similar to that of getElementsByClassName(). It's supposed to traverse every node in the DOM and push nodes with a matching class into an array. I tried to use something similar to Crockford's walk_the_DOM method, however, mine isn't working. The function retrieves nodes on the first DOM level, but doesn't go deeper. Could someone give me a hint as to what's going wrong? Here's the code:

```
var getNodesWithClassname = function(classname) {
  var a = document.body;
  var ar = [];
  var getNodes = function(obj, classname) {
    if (obj.hasChildNodes()) {
      var child = obj.firstElementChild;
      while (child) {
        if (child.className === classname) {
          ar.push(child)
        }
        child = child.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
  }
  getNodes(a, classname);
  return ar;
};
```

Comment: How does it *not work*?

Comment: There's no recursion anywhere, which plays a big part why your code only traverses one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need recursion if the element is an element with children:

```
var getNodesWithClassname = function(classname) {
  var a = document.body;
  var ar = [];
  var getNodes = function(obj, classname) {
    if (obj.hasChildNodes()) {
      var child = obj.firstElementChild;
      while (child) {
        if (child.className === classname) {
          ar.push(child)
        }
        if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.childElementCount > 0) {
          getNodes(child, classname);
        }
        child = child.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
  }
  getNodes(a, classname);
  return ar;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no recursion, there should be a call to `getNodes()` inside of the function `getNodes`.  Without recursion, it can not go deeper into the tree.

There needs to be a `getNodes(child, classname);` call.

Comment: After child = child.nextElementSibling?

Comment: If you did that, you would skip the first child in every set. Needs to go before.

Answer (score 0):

A much more simpler method would be just to take all elements and filter out which ones have the class name. No recursion needed, just a one-run loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/3weJc/

```
var getNodesWithClassname = function (classname) {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var nodesLength = nodes.length;
    var results = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < nodesLength; ++i){
        if(nodes[i].className === classname) results.push(nodes[i]);  
    }

    return results;
};
```